# Installing 5.1 hangs in boot

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

I have a Microsoft Surface Laptop 3. I tried to boot up elementary on a USB stick but it just goes blank after grub. Here are the things I tried:

- disabled secure boot
- tried nomodeset acpi=off kernel parameters
- removed the quiet and splash kernel parameters

Nothing works. After pressing enter in grub the screen goes blank and is stuck. Even with the quiet parameter removed it shows nothing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think there is a close enough answer: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/20905/installation-on-new-dell-xps-7390-clamshell

Answer (score 0):

If you press ESC on boot (where the logo appears), you should be able to see the debug messages of boot process.

Comment: Didn't work. I don't get the boot logo. It is blank after grub. And like I mentioned removing the `quiet` from the kernel parameters usually shows the debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like support for the Microsoft Surface Laptop 3 has yet to be mainlined.
However, there appears to be support for it from the [linux-surface project](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface).
You can find a dedicated page on your device [here](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Surface-Laptop-3).
I'm thinking you might be able to get your current installation working by using a `chroot` from the installer and installing the linux-surface kernel according to [their instructions](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup#Debian--Ubuntu).
[Debian's RescueLive Wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/RescueLive) has a great guide on how to `chroot`.